# How to Play Video On Gmail From Android

Tags: android

**Objective :**


i want to Record the video from my android device and upload to gmail and the uploaded video should 
Play when the play button click.

**Want to Know :**


Is there any inbuild option to play video on gmail or we should upload video to youtube from that share 
 the video url to gmail.

**What I Have Done :**


I have recorded video and i try to upload the video on gmail but it's not play it shows like a downloadd file 

Below code i have used.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String paths="file:///"+path;
Log.v("path", paths);
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(paths);
sharingIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{photo});
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Birthday Wish");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, videoUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Video using"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GMail has a feature that can allow you to do this either way. Even when doing it inside a desktop web browser but don't quote me on that. I think you may want to think about utilizing YouTube for this.